# How do I block ip using Norton Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, comodo-firewall

I need block all ip as described at this page using Norton:

https://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-451-4810-.html

I mean how can I apply these settings:

> Rule 5
>
> Action : Block (Also select the check box 'Log as a firewall event if 
>   this rule is fired')
>
> Protocol : IP
>
> Direction : In/Out
>
> Description : Block and Log All Unmatching Requests
>
> Source Address : Any Address
>
> Destination Address : Any Address
>
> IP Details : IP Protocol : Any
>
> Click 'OK' in the 'Firewall Ruleset' interface.

Note: There isn't any IP protocol setting in Norton, there are only udp, tcp, both.

Comment: You just need to use “both” for “any”.

Comment: Why is this flagged as `comodo-firewall`?  This has nothing to do with [Comodo Firewall](https://personalfirewall.comodo.com/).  You are using a Norton product but failed to provide enough information, like which Norton product your using.  Knowing which edition you have, will help us, submit a relevant useful answer.  Screenshots of the UI, will help us, since many Norton products are paid software.

Comment: Hi I'm using Norton Security 22. I didn't want to upload a screenshot because the program's language isn't English. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

IP is the underlying protocol on the Internet and has two transport mechanisms Transimission Control Protocol (TCP) and User Datagram Protocol (UDP).  TCP is used for persistent connections (like ssh, http, etc.) and UDP is generall used for services not requiring a persistent connection (like DNS and ping).

You want to block TCP or UDP services.  The article is providing you guidance on how to choose what services to block, not all IP traffic.

IP blocking is also possible but based on your question and the reference this is about choosing which services (or ports) and the protocol (TCP or UDP).

To be safe, for a given service (port) block both.  If you want to block persistent traffic on a service like DNS (which DNS does not use) then choose TCP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I'm still in doubt which one to choose.

Comment: Choose both if in doubt.  For the most part, for well known services they use one or the other so blocking both is the best first choice.